# cambiar el formato de varias columnas de un DataFrame con melt simultáneamente

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un DataFrame que contiene información de  varios productos (Vegetales), los productos pueden ir de 1 a 8 ingredientes. 
En el DataFrame se especifica la descripción del producto y los ingredientes y porcentajes de cada ingrediente, Además de la cantidad de producto vendido (en toneladas).

El dataFrame está organizado de tal forma que cada renglon corresponde a un producto.

[image: dataframe original]

Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el formato del DataFrame utilizando **melt** de tal manera que los 8 ingredientes queden en una sola columna, al igual que los cortes de cada ingrediente y el porcentaje de cada uno. para que que yo pueda multiplicar el valor de las ventas (Tons) por el porcentaje de cada ingrediente y conocer al final cuanto se vendió de cada ingrediente en toneladas.

[codigo en google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19pZo4mt2iO_0Cq1YEW8T6Oe5lbs7-OSf)

```
import pandas as pd
# Se Crea el dataFrame de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame({'producto':  {0: 'Broccoli Florets', 1: 'Broccoli cuts', 
                             2: 'Mezcla Calif'},
                'ingrediente 1': {0: 'broccoli', 1: 'broccoli ', 2: 'broccoli '},
                '% Ingred 1': {0: 100, 1: 50, 2: 50},
               'corte Ingred 1': {0: 'florets', 1: 'cuts', 2:'' },
              'ingrediente 2': {0: '',1: 'Coliflor', 2: 'Coliflor'},
                '% Ingred 2': {0: 0, 1: 50, 2: 25},
               'corte Ingred 2': {0: '', 1: 'florets', 2:'florets' },
               'ingrediente 3': {0: '',1: '', 2: 'Zanahoria'},
                '% Ingred 3': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 25},
               'corte Ingred 3': {0: '', 1: '', 2:'rodaja' },
               'Mat Cabeza': {0: 100, 1: 50, 2: 35},
               'ventas (tons)': {0: 1000, 1: 5000, 2: 3500},

# se reorganiza el dataframe para que los datos de cada ingrediente queden juntos                  })
df = df.loc[:,['producto','ventas (tons)','Mat Cabeza','ingrediente 1','corte Ingred 1','% Ingred 1',
          'ingrediente 2','corte Ingred 2','% Ingred 2',
          'ingrediente 3','corte Ingred 3','% Ingred 3']]
# se muestra el DataFrame
df.head()
```

el formato como se desea la tabla es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ha usado melt de la siguiente manera

```
ingredients = ['ingrediente 1','ingrediente 2','ingrediente 3']

base_organizada_ing = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['producto','Mat Cabeza', 'ventas (tons)','corte Ingred 1','corte Ingred 2','corte Ingred 3', '% Ingred 1','% Ingred 2','% Ingred 3'], 
                      value_vars= ingredients, value_name="id_ingred",var_name=['ingrediente'])
```

melt para las columnas de ingredientes si funciona, pero cuando trato de hacer un segundo melt para apilar las columnas de cortes y un tercero para apilar los porcentajes, se van duplicando los registros.

por lo que deseo saber de que manera se puede hacer la apilación de varias columnas de manera simultanea o como reorganizar la tabla para poder obtener la venta en toneladas de cada ingrediente.